# Filter to speed up convergence of geometric series

Tags: filter-design, adaptive-filters, non-linear

I want to speed up convergence of geometric series
$\ \  lim + c^n \ \ $ where $|c| < 1$ and $lim$ is not known.
A basic low-pass filter, here Butterworth, is good for $-1 < c < 0$ but not $0 < c < 1$:

```
butter  N 2  Wn 0.5:  [.293 .586 .293] / [1 0 .172]
|response|: [100 100  99  97  88  71  47  25  10   3   0]
(-.8) ^ n  [100 -80  64 -51  41 -33  26 -21  17 -13]  ->  [29 35 -4 -7  1  1  0  0  0  0]
.8 ^ n     [100  80  64  51  41  33  26  21  17  13]  ->  [29 82 90 62 45 38 31 25 20 16]
```

Is there a filter that does both ?

Why: many iterative processes that generate points $X_n$ in 1d, 3d, 100d
converge to an $X_{lim}$ slowly,
but roughly geometrically:
either one-sided like $.8^n$, or oscillating like $(-.8)^n$ .
It would be nice to have a simple, robust filter that speeds up both.

[Shanks transformation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shanks_transformation)
is a nonlinear transform that works really well on geometric series.
But on linear input 1 2 3 it'll divide by 0.
(Check for that, push on regardless ? practical, but unsatisfying.)
(I believe that 
[Aitken's delta-squared process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aitken%27s_delta-squared_process)
is the same as Shanks -- not sure.)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that in the case with positive $c$ you have a DC desired signal ($lim$) and a low frequency noise ($c^n$). In the case when $c$ is negative you have a high frequency noise signal, which is of course much easier to separate from the desired DC value.

If you figure out some way to estimate $c$ (sign and magnitude) you can use a simple FIR filter

```
b=[1,-c]/(1-c); a=1;
```

which will exactly eliminate the exponentially decaying noise:

$$y[n]=\frac{1}{1-c}(x[n]-cx[n-1])=\frac{1}{1-c}(lim+c^n-c\cdot lim - c\cdot c^{n-1})=lim$$

Comment: "figure out some way to estimate c" looks tough in the wild -- there may be a sum of several $c$ s.  Just fit ratios of the last few $X_n$, smooth ? (I thought this would be a common problem, don't want to reinvent this wheel.)

Comment: @denis: It might be a common problem, but I don't know about it. I'm afraid that with a *linear* filter you can't do much more than what I wrote in my answer. It may be possible to come up with a smart adaptive algorithm for estimating the value(s) of $c$.